# Rails: Using Links to pass POST parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
    <%= link_to "Follow", { :controller => "friendship", :action => "follow",:id=> friend.id} , :remote => true, :class => "follow_user" %>
```

1. How do I use 'links' to pass argument 'id' as a POST variable and not as a parameter in the URL?
2. And then, How do I make 'follow' action in 'friendship' controller only accept POST variable so that nobody can use 'http://localhost:3000/friendship/follow?id=8' in the URL to perform the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `method: :post` to your `link_to` options.
2. Use a constraint on your route, or check if request is POST with `request.post?`in your controller.

Comment: `:method => :post` in link_to, and `request.post?` check in my controller seems to work fine, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try
`<%= button_to "Follow", { controller: "friendship", action: "follow", id: friend.id}, remote: true, class: "follow_user", method: :post %>`